# Launching one widget from a button inside another widget

Tags: javascript, arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-custom-widget

Suppose I have created a button inside a custom `InfoTemplate` (aka 'popup') widget in my `Web AppBuilder` app:

```
 var editButton = new Button({
     label: "Edit Schedule",
     onClick: function () {
         editButton.setDisabled(true); //disable the edit button on first click
     }
 });

 editButton.startup();
```

What I want is to launch another widget called `'TaskManager'` when the `onClick` event is triggered.
It seems like I need to use a library class called `WidgetManager` but I can find any practical example for my scenario. It seems like I need to use something like this:

```
 openWidget(widget)
```

The `openWidget` method requires the Widget ID, which I am having trouble locating in my app (I know the name is `TaskManager` from the `manifest.json` file but can't find the `id` attribute). 
I've also seen example where a function is created, I assume inside the `InfoTemplate` widget, that will point to the `TaskManager` widget and can be called inside the click event:

```
   _openTaskManager: function () {
       var taskManager, sbc;
       var widgetCfg = this._getWidgetConfig('CustomInfoTemplate');
       if (widgetCfg) {
           sbc = WidgetManager.getInstance().getWidgetsByName('TaskManager')[0];
           sbc._resizeToMax();
           sbc.setOpenedIds([widgetCfg.id]);
       }
  },
```

then => `_openTaskManager();`

Am I on the right track? Is there an easy way to do this or am I way off? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem I ran into was that I am trying to enhance a very old version of WAB, version 1.2 (I think the current version is 2.4 or something) which cannot use the same methods, such as `.triggerWidgetOpen`. Of course, there was little documentation on how to practically achieve this in the esri documentation, but here is the solution that was pointed out to me on their forum. First, make sure that you have added the `WidgetManager` package correctly at the top of your script and then create and instance. Then, you have to go to the main `config.json` file and find the index of the widget you want to launch under `'widgets': [...]` In this case my `TaskManager` widget was the 9th widget in the list, this index[8]. Use this to create a variable. You then have to use the `HeadController` widget to open the desired widget like this:

```
 var editButton = new Button({
     label: "Edit Schedule"
 });
 editButton.on('click', lang.hitch(this, function () {
     editButton.setDisabled(true); //disable the edit button on first click
     var wm = WidgetManager.getInstance();

     var tm = wm.appConfig.widgetPool.widgets[8];
     var hc = WidgetManager.getInstance().getWidgetsByName("HeaderController")[0];
     hc.setOpenedIds([tm.id]);

     editButton.setDisabled(false);
 }));

 editButton.startup();
```

In my case, simply using `.openWidget` and plugging in the `WidgetManager` instance didn't throw any errors, but didn't open the Task Manager widget either. Hope this helps anyone dealing with this issue in an old version of WEB.